# Purpose of VMware setting 'pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.autohide'

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

Does anyone know what the purpose of the setting `pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.autohide` in the VMware configuration file `preference.ini` is?
I can't see any difference between `pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.autohide = "true"` and `pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.autohide = "false"` and I also can't find any documentation about this setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option helps to hide by default the VMware top bar in full-screen view.
The purpose is to get almost all of the VMWare Player UI
out of the way so you can focus entirely on the guest OS.

For auto-hiding the bar in in full-screen mode use:

```
pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.autohide = "TRUE"
```

To shrink the size of the hidden toolbar, specify zero pixels.
This will still keep a couple of pixels on top, so it's hardly noticeable:

```
pref.fullscreen.toolbarpixels = "0"
```

To fully get rid of the bar use:

```
pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.nobar = "TRUE"
```

To further hide all the hints that VMWare Player likes to keep popping up, use:

```
hints.hideAll = "true"
pref.vmplayer.exit.vmAction = "poweroff"
```

Comment: Perfect explanation! Many thanks. And this also works in VMware Workstation (```pref.fullscreen.autohide = "TRUE"```).
PS: Unfortunately, until now I could not find a way in VMware Workstation to fully get rid of this bar (```pref.fullscreen.nobar = "TRUE"``` does not work). The only option I found so far is ```[ ] Show toolbar edge when unpinned in full screen``` which hides the bar, but unfortunately does not deactivate the bar at all.